# Is there an iOS Native equivalent to the JavaScript client SDK getUserInfo

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to retrieve my UserIdentity from the server in a Native iOS app, but I see no equivalent to the JavaScript `WL.Client.getUserInfo()` method in the iOS SDK.  Is there a way to do this in iOS?

Comment: What version of MobileFirst? Are you using OAuth? WLResourceRequest? Or invokeProcedure? This may be what you are looking for: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/Classes/WLAuthorizationManager.html?lang=en

Comment: Nathan, I am using MFP 7.1.  No, not using OAuth.  Using WLResourceRequest.  I'm working on a solution where I will just have the client ask for the information from an adapter procedure.  I think that will accomplish what I need.

Comment: If you use WLResourceRequest, you automatically use OAuth as well, they come together. Since you are using OAuth, the link I gave you above should work.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are probably right.  That probably is a good option, although I think my approach is going to work as well.

Comment: @DSchultz_mo, make sure to write whatever you decide as an answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am using it wrong, but userIdentity() always seems to return nil but I do see valid data in deviceIdenity().

Nonetheless, I decided to implement this in an adapter procedure.  After authenticating, the app calls the adapter procedure to fetch the user's profile information before doing anything that will require that profile data.